# Yii query not returning null when table is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, blogs

I have an empty table tbl_rating that has user_id and post_id columns in it. In my Post view, I am trying to check to see if the post being viewed has already been rated by the user viewing it. I'm using the following in the view.

```
<?php
$sql='SELECT * FROM tbl_rating WHERE post_id='.$model->id.' AND user_id='.Yii::app()->user->getId().';';
        $connection=Yii::app()->db;
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
        $query=$command->query();
if($query != null):
?>
<p>You've already rated this post.</p>
```

However, when I view any post, it says "You've already rated this post." even though there are no ratings. Does the query method return something other than null when it doesn't find any rows in the table?

Comment: Is your hostname is localhost? Edit your etc/hosts file and test other domain such that example.local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it that way will returns an CDbQueryResult so you need to do

```
if($query->rowCount !== 0) { }
```

(see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#query-detail)

I wouldn't recommend doing it that way though.
If you have setup your relations correctly you should be able to do something like

```
if($model->rating !== null) { }
```

See the following for examples on declearing active record relationships: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship

Comment: The rowCount method worked, thanks. I am curious as to how I would set up a relation so that I could check if a Post has a rating with a specified author_id. There isn't a way to use the query I used in my initial question as a relation is there? Currently my Post model has many Ratings and has many Comments, and a Rating has only one Post and one User.

Comment: Found a way to do this. Added the following relation: 'rating'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Rating', 'post_id', 'condition'=>'user_id='.Yii::app()->user->getId())